# What is the database to use for rolling logs?

Tags: logging

I once read about a database for rolling logs.  It was for keeping server data over a fixed period and basically it worked like a huge circular buffer on disk.  Since all the space was statically allocated, it didn't suffer from problems of purging old records and the like.

I tried to find the name of that setup today and just can't seem to locate it.  I'm recording server log messages (IP traffic mostly) and I only want to keep the data for a set # of days, and just let the wrap around and overwrite the old data, but I still want to be able to mine that data.

Does anyone else remember hearing about it or what the name of it was?  I do know it was open source and had been out several years, so its probably at least 3-5 years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was it [RRDTool](http://www.mrtg.org/rrdtool/)?

Comment: Very nice. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) with [capped collections](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Capped+Collections). Works perfectly for logs.